MacBook Pro M1 won’t accept WiFi password - it’s definitely correct
My MacBook Pro (2019 M1) will not join the internet.  When I put in the password it accepts it then attempts to connect but just goes back to the password dialogue box. The password is definitely correct.
It also can no longer see our second WiFi network nor my phone’s hotspot but it sees my husband’s hotspot fine and logs on with no issues.
My Mac is up to date and this issue started yesterday.
All other devices working fine.
I’m a freelancer so desperate to get this fixed. We have a Ubiquity system installed - the engineer came out to look at it - he updated the system but everything is working as it should. My MacBook also connected fine after the visit but subsequently started having this issue.
I have rebooted everything - including the Ubiquity at least three times and it did not solve the issue.

First, type the password in a text editor to make sure the keyboard is working. Copy and paste the password into the connection dialog. Failing that, disconnect all wired peripherals, start up in safe mode, and test. If you still can’t connect, forget the network in the Wi-Fi settings and try to add it again.

I’d start by ‘forgetting’ the Wi-Fi network first, then trying the other steps.

Troubleshooting Steps for MacBook Pro WiFi Connectivity Issue

Forget the WiFi network and reconnect

Go to System Preferences > Network
Select Wi-Fi
Click Advanced
Find your network in the list, select it, and click the minus (-) button
Click OK and then Apply
Reconnect and enter the network password again


Check for network configuration issues

Go to System Preferences > Network
Select Wi-Fi
Click Advanced
Ensure Automatically join this network is checked
Verify that the correct network is listed and appropriately positioned


Reset network settings

Go to System Preferences > Network
Select Wi-Fi
Click Advanced
Remove any extra network profiles listed
Click OK and Apply
Restart your MacBook and try reconnecting


Reset the SMC and NVRAM

SMC Reset

Turn off your Mac
Press and Hold Shift+Ctrl+Opt+Power for 10 seconds
Release all keys
Press the power button to start your Mac


NVRAM Reset

Turn off your Mac
Press and hold Opt+Cmd+P+R for 20 seconds
Release the keys and let your Mac restart




Update or reinstall macOS

Check Updates at System Preferences > Software Update
Reinstall macOS: If up to date, consider reinstalling to resolve software issues


Check network security settings

Verify: Ubiquity system’s security settings are compatible with your MacBook


Try Safe Mode

Restart Mac by holding Shift immediately after the startup sound
Release the key when the login window appears
Try connecting to Wi-Fi in Safe Mode




This looks like AI generated nonsense to promote your repair company. I assume that nobody at your repair company knows anything except how to ask ChatGPT?
